# Declare command and shell expansion

Tags: bash, declare

I stumbled by accident on the following `bash` behaviour, which is for me kind of unexpected.

```
# The following works
$ declare bar=Hello                               # Line 1
$ declare -p bar                                  # Line 2
declare -- bar="Hello"
$ foo=bar                                         # Line 3
$ declare ${foo}=Bye                              # Line 4
$ declare -p bar                                  # Line 5
declare -- bar="Bye"
# The following fails, though
$ declare -a array=( A B C )                      # Line 6
$ declare -p array                                # Line 7
declare -a array=([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C")
$ foo=array                                       # Line 8
$ declare -a ${foo}=([0]="A" [1]="XXX" [2]="C")   # Line 9
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
# Quoting the assignment fixes the problem
$ declare -a "${foo}=(A YYY C)"                   # Line 10
$ declare -p array                                # Line 11
declare -a array=([0]="A" [1]="YYY" [2]="C")
```

Since shell expansion

1. Brace expansion
2. - Tilde expansion
   - Parameter and variable expansion
   - Arithmetic expansion
   - Process substitution
   - Command substitution
3. Word splitting
4. Filename expansion

is performed on the command line after it has been split into tokens (followed by quote removal) but before the final command is executed, I would not have expected line 9 to fail.

**Which is the rationale behind it, that makes `bash` not accept line 9?** Or, said differently, **what am I missing in the way line 9 is processed by `bash` that makes it fail but makes line 10 succeed?**

In any case, quoting is not always going to straightforwardly work and it would require extra attention in case the array elements are strings with e.g. spaces.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n5302 "A word is an assignment if it appears at the beginning of a simple command, or after another assignment word.  This is context-dependent, so it cannot be handled in the grammar." So the parser can't handle `(` like it would if it appeared elsewhere, and leaves it to the next level, which may barf on something that isn't a *name*.

Comment: Observation: use `set -x` and see the difference between `declare -a array=( B C )`, `declare -a "array=( B C )"`, `declare -a "array=(" B C ")"` and similar variants.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, this is what I intended with the last sentence in the question.

@muru The fact that information is in a comment in the `bash` implementation sounds like it was worth asking this question :) ...I now get that the assignment is not recognised as such since it is not at the beginning of a simple command, but this is somehow expected, isn't it? I mean, what we call *assignment* is indeed an argument of `declare` or is it wrong to think in this way? Still I do not get the difference between line 4 and line 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr; I think it's just a syntax quirk, and you shouldn't presume some grand design behind it.

Bash is using a bison/yacc-generated [parser](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y), but just like with many other languages (C, perl, etc), it's not a "clean" parser, but it's also keeping some *state* separate/parallel to the grammar in the `parser_state` variable.

A flag kept in that state variable is `PST_ASSIGNOK`. That will be set when some builtin which was parsed as a `WORD` token had `ASSIGNMENT_BUILTIN` in its flags.

Such "assignment builtins" are `local`, `typeset`, `declare`, `alias`, `export` and `readonly`.

The `PST_ASSIGNOK` will direct the parser to consider parentheses as part of a `WORD` token when used after an assignment at the right of such a builtin. But it will NOT change the rules which determine whether the current token is actually an [assignment](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c?id=6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed#n410): Since `${foo}=(...)` is not an acceptable assignment, it will not be parsed as a single word, and the parentheses will trigger a syntax error just like in `echo foo(bar)`.

After a command line was parsed, it will be *expanded*, and as part of the expansions, any compound assignment (`WORD` which was marked with `W_COMPASSIGN`) like `var=(1 2)` will be performed and replaced with `var`, which will then be passed as an argument to a builtin like `declare`. But if `declare`, after all the expansions, gets an argument of the form `var=(...)`, it will parse and expand it itself again.

So, `varname=foo; declare "$var=(1 2 3)"` may be similar to `declare foo='(1 2 3)'`. Or to `declare foo=(1 2 3)`, depending on whether the variable was already defined:

```
$ declare 'foo=(1 2 3)'; typeset -p foo
declare -- foo="(1 2 3)"
$ declare foo=(1); typeset -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="1")
$ declare 'foo=(1 2 3)'; typeset -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
```

I don't think it's a good idea to rely on this corner case:

```
$ declare 'bar=(1 ( )'; typeset -p bar
declare -- bar="(1 ( )"
$ declare bar=(1); typeset -p bar
declare -a bar=([0]="1")
$ declare 'bar=(1 ( )'; typeset -p bar
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: It still looks to me not completely logic and your `tl;dr;` in the beginning is probably the take home message. I naively thought that the parser was building up the *assignment argument* of `declare` and later, somehow, this assignment was carried out. This way of thinking seems not to work, though. I am not sure I'm getting the point of your snippets. If you add `-a` to the first `declare`, you get the output of the third one, which makes sense to me, since you'd explicitly say that `foo` or `bar` are arrays from the beginning on. In line 4 VS line 9 in my question I thought I was coherent.

Comment: I've tried to expand a bit: basically, a command line is first parsed by the yacc parser, and then, AFTER the line was parsed, the expansions are performed as part of _executing the command line_; a word like `foo=(1 2)` will expand to `foo` while assigning it `(1 2)` to the `foo` array. `local`, `declare`, etc will then mark the variable appropriately. But those builtins will also parse an argument like `foo=(1 2)` _themselves_, if that's what they got after all the expansions (eg. as a result of `v=q; declare -a "$v=(r t)"`)

Comment: The point of my snippets is to point out related quirks of the declare, local, typeset, etc builtins, which are quite unexpected IMHO.

Comment: I was not aware that **any assignment will be expanded to its variable name which will be passed as an argument to the builtin; if it was quoted, it's the builtin itself which will reparse and expand it**. This helps a lot. Still I think it is not completely clear the order in which the operations take place. I mean, I see now that `v=q; declare -a "$v=(r t)"` postpone the assignment to the `declare` builtin, but why should this line without quotes fail? I am totally with you in the last comment.

Comment: `declare -a $v=(r t)` fails much earlier, in the parser. Basically the `token_is_assignment()` -> `assignment()` function does not accept `$v=` as a possible assignment, the test a [line 5593](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n5173) will not match, the `(` will not be considered as part of a `WORD`, and the line will fail the same way as `foo (bar)`.

Comment: Will instead `v=q; declare $v=Hello` (without quotes) pass such a check? If yes I am puzzle because `$v=` is not a valid bash assignment, if not then I am puzzled because this is somehow accepted by the shell... I think we are almost there and I really appreciate your explanations. I tried to read the C code of the parser, but it is not so immediate...

Comment: All this thing only applies to compound assignments, ie arrays. In the case of `v=q; declare $v=Hello`, there are no `(` or `)` metacharacters to trip on (even `echo $v=Hello` will work!), and declare will be passed a `q=Hello` argument which it will parse itself.

Comment: Thanks for digging out all the details. I think I have now a better overview. And, yes, it is definitely quirky! `:)`

Comment: When you write *The `PST_ASSIGNOK` will direct the parser to consider parentheses as part of `WORD`s when used after an assignment at the right of such a builtin. But it will NOT change the rules which determine whether the current token is actually an assignment*, where/how does the parser accepts `$v=Hello` if the rules to determine whether the current token is actually an assignment are still the same?

Comment: The parser does not accept `$v=Hello` as an assignment, just just tokenize it as word (exactly as `$v=Hello`, the `$v` will be expanded _later_). I've already pointed you to [line 5173](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n5173) of `parse.y`: there the parser checks if the following character is a `=`, if it's part of a valid assignment, if the state is in assignok mode, etc and then PEEKS at next char to see if it's an opening parenthesis (`if MBTEST(peek_char == '(')`). If any of those conditions are not met, nothing special happens.

Comment: I think I read all the comments and the parser code like *too many times*. Just to be sure. Is then the point that `(` and `)` are used to split the full line in tokens and then `$v=(...` triggers `$v=` to be seen as token which is in turn identified as not valid assignment, whereas in `$v=Hello` there is no `(` and this is seen as whole token, which is then valid?

[By the way I was reading at line 5593 since you wrote like that in your previous command, sorry.]

Comment: Yes, I had written 5593, sorry, but the link was to 5173. Yes, `$v=Hello` is will turn into a `WORD` token, but `$v=(3)`, will turn into four: `WORD`, `(`, `WORD` and `)`, which will be rejected by the yacc parser.